# Symfony database connection without using database.yml

Tags: symfony1, database-connection

Let's say you have a situation where your Symfony application cannot get its database connection information from the `databases.yml` file.

In this situation, how can you set up a database connection "by hand" (let's assume Doctrine as the ORM)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe use "[Opening New Connections](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine1/en/latest/en/manual/introduction-to-connections.html#opening-new-connections)"

```
// bootstrap.php

// ...
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=testdb;host=127.0.0.1';
$user = 'dbuser';
$password = 'dbpass';

$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
$conn = Doctrine_Manager::connection($dbh);
```

Check as well those SO answers:

- [How do you override your team's default databases.yml in Doctrine for using your local settings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3240237/how-do-you-override-your-teams-default-databases-yml-in-doctrine-for-using-your)
- [How can you/Is it feasible to override Doctrine_Connection in Symfony?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4064750/how-can-you-is-it-feasible-to-override-doctrine-connection-in-symfony)

Comment: But how do you cause this connection to be the default connection in the same manner as the connection information in `databases.yml` turns into the default connection for the rest of the application? Or does it become the default connection merely by running in `bootstrap.php`?

Comment: In fact, you "simply" want to override the default behavior (processing something else instead of `databases.yml`) ? Edited my answer.